# Passing Tailwind class as a prop in React

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, react-props, react-functional-component

I am creating a reusable component button to which I want to pass two Tailwind classes as props and use them dynamically.

Here is my component:

```
function Button({ primary, secondry, label, onClick }) {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={(e) => onClick(e)}
      className={`bg-${primary} py-0.5 px-3 rounded text-white font-semibold text-xl border-2 border-${primary} hover:bg-${secondry} hover:text-${primary} cursor-pointer duration-300`}
    >
      {label}
    </button>
  );
}
```

This is how I am using the component:

```
<Button
label={"Cancel"}
primary="red-700"
secondry="zinc-900"
onClick={(e) => navigate("/customers")}
/>
```

However, the classes are not being applied. This is how it looks:

[image: How button looks]

Comment: Tailwind does not support dynamic classes. This has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71937890/tailwind-css-classes-show-up-in-the-dom-but-the-styles-are-not-being-applied

Answer (score 5):

Try to pass the whole string `bg-red-700` like this like this

```
function Button({ bgprimary, textprimary, borderprimary, bgsecondary, label, onClick }) {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={(e) => onClick(e)}
      className={`${bgprimary} py-0.5 px-3 rounded text-white font-semibold text-xl border-2 ${borderprimary} hover:${bgsecondary} hover:${textprimary} cursor-pointer duration-300`}
    >
      {label}
    </button>
  );
}
```

And use it like

```
<Button
label={"Cancel"}
bgprimary="bg-red-700"
textprimary="text-red-700"
borderprimary="border-red-700"
bgsecondary="bg-zinc-900"
onClick={(e) => navigate("/customers")}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to pass it like this

className={`bg-['${primary}']  ....`}

Comment: As has been commented on the question itself, this will not work with Tailwind. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71937890/tailwind-css-classes-show-up-in-the-dom-but-the-styles-are-not-being-applied

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer so that people can get the context and the thought process behind it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using `tailwind-merge` and `clsx` packages you can achieve this:

Create a utility `cn` function like this and then import this wherever you need to use it.

```
import { clsx, type ClassValue } from "clsx";
import { twMerge } from "tailwind-merge";

export function cn(...inputs: ClassValue[]) {
  return twMerge(clsx(inputs));
}
```

Use it like this:

```
function Button({ primary, secondary, label, onClick }) {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={(e) => onClick(e)}
      className={cn(
        `bg-${primary}`,
        "py-0.5",
        "px-3",
        "rounded",
        "text-white",
        "font-semibold",
        "text-xl",
        "border-2",
        `border-${primary}`,
        `hover:bg-${secondary}`,
        `hover:text-${primary}`,
        "cursor-pointer",
        "duration-300",
      )}
    >
      {label}
    </button>
  );
}
```