# tailwind - some class not works

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I use tailwind in nextjs project, and when I restart the server (I mean start the server again with npm run dev) some tailwind code not working when I write class property in "inspect Element" it works but not tailwind code.

not works: w-1/2 (width: 25%), lg:w-0 (media screen and(max-width: 1024px) {code})

my tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    screens: {
      sm: { max: "640px" },
      md: { max: "768px" },
      lg: { max: "1024px" },
      xl: { max: "1280px" },
      "2xl": { max: "1536px" },
    }
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

my global.css file:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@import "./reset.css";
```

Comment: That is the correct answer!!!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72007089/passing-tailwind-class-as-a-prop-in-react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the classes fully `w-1/2` instead of partially like `1/2`. As tailwind doesn't support dynamic classes.

Try the following code.

```
function Component({ width}) {
  return (
    <div
      className={`${width}`}
    >
      Hello there
    </div>
  );
}
```

And use it as

```
<Component
width={"w-1/2"}
/>
```

##### Edit: Using [Safelisting classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes)

As a last resort, Tailwind offers Safelisting classes

> Safelisting is a last-resort, and should only be used in situations where it’s impossible to scan certain content for class names. These situations are rare, and you should almost never need this feature.

In your example,you want to have different width. You can use [regular expressions](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#using-regular-expressions) to include all the widths you want using `pattern`

In `tailwind.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{html,js}',
    './components/**/*.{html,js}',
  ],
  safelist: [
    {
      pattern: /w-(1/2|2/2|1/6|2/6)/, // You can define all the width you desire

    },
  ],
  // ...
}
```

---

Comment: I use safelist and I think that is the best way to solve this problem, thank you for your answer

Comment: I have added the safelist in the solution , to make it complete. Hope you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

you have to create an extend object with your personalized code inside like this:

```
theme: {
    extend: {
      screens: {
  
        'clg': '1090px',   
  
        'cxl': '1159px',      
  
        'c2xl': '1213px',
  
        'c3x1': '1373px',
        
        'c4x1': '1480px',
        
        'c5x1': '1579px',

        'c6x1': '1679px',

        'c7x1': '1740px',

        'c8x1': '1820px',
        
      },
```

Comment: and w-1/4? why not work? w-1/2 this works....

Comment: maybe tailwind don't understand perfectly, i always use what the documentation says https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens

Comment: no, you don't understand me, in some div class I use for example w-1/2 or w-2  which means "width: some number" but when I use w-1/4 which means width: 25% it does not work, also I can't see in inspect element

Comment: I understand  what you're saying

Comment: For 3 hours I do everything but finally can't resolve the problem, my brain is dead

Comment: maybe try to save the tailwind.config.js sometimes I have this problem things stops working than I save the file and it's comeback  working

Comment: probably you already did this i wonder

Comment: I solved it, so I have a modal layout that has props "style" which I use for tailwind code, I edited "style" with "className" and now it works!  thank Gabriel for your answer and support