# Arbitrary values from Context not working in tailwind

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm working with a context that provides the colors chosen by the user, but when i try to access the content using arbitrary colors in tailwind its not rendering.

```
import React from "react";

import { IContext, IProviderProps } from "./Settings.structure";

const SettingsContext = React.createContext({} as IContext);

function SettingsProvider({ children }: IProviderProps) {
  const settings = {
    colors: {
      primary: "#2EB5AC",
      secondary: "#521AA3",
      tertiary: "#FB7100",
    },
  };

  return (
    <SettingsContext.Provider
      value={React.useMemo(
        () => ({
          settings,
        }),
        [settings]
      )}
    >
      {children}
    </SettingsContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

```
import { useSettings } from "@/hooks/settings"
import React from "react";

export default function CheckList() {
  const {settings} = useSettings();
  return (
    <div className={`bg-[${settings.colors.primary}]`}/>
  )
}
```

Comment: Dynamically generated class names will not be parsed by Tailwind and included in the resulting CSS file. You have to include the full class name somewhere in your code or in a whitelist in `tailwind.config.js`. See: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tailwind CSS classes show up in the DOM, but the styles are not being applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71937890/tailwind-css-classes-show-up-in-the-dom-but-the-styles-are-not-being-applied)

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useSettings } from "@/hooks/settings"
import React from "react";

export default function CheckList() {
  const {settings} = useSettings();
  const bgcolors = {
    primary: 'bg-[#2EB5AC]',
    secondary: 'bg-[#521AA3]',
    tertiary: 'bg-[#FB7100]',
  };
  return (
    <div className={bgcolors[settings.primary]} />
  )
}
```

For more detail, Please check this docs.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#migrating-to-the-jit-engine

https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode